# Taking a single record from array returned by result

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

I have following statement to get record from entity framework.

```
 cars car = db.auto.Find(type);
```

This statement returns more than one records I need to pick just anyone since they are all same. I tried this

```
  car car=db.auto.Find(type).Take(1);
```

But it doesnt work. Please let me know how to pick just single record from the result.
Thanks
Tarik

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`FirstOrDefault`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.firstordefault%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). That would return first item from the collection or `null`, if none is found.

```
 car car=db.auto.Find(type).FirstOrDefault();
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `First` method:

```
  car car=db.auto.Find(type).First();
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
car car=db.auto.Find(type)[0]
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`First`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb291976%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to return the first item returned from your query:

```
car car=db.auto.Find(type).First();
```

Or [`Single`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb155325%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), which will return the first item, but also error if there is more than one item:

```
car car=db.auto.Find(type).Single();
```

Note that both of these options will throw an error if there are no items returned. If that's a possibility, you might want to use [`FirstOrDefault`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb340482%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) or [`SingleOrDefault`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb342451%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). These methods will return `null` if the result set is empty.